# How to handle created Classes in javascript

Tags: javascript, class

In my project, I have many `.js` files, I made each js file as a `Class` using `prototype.js`. For example, I have the following js files.

- one.js   -- Class name is "One"
- two.js   -- Class name is "Two"
- three.js -- Class name is "Three"
- Four.js  -- Class name is "Four"

Each file depends on other js files. So, the possible structure of js files is something like this:

**four.js**

```
var Four = Class.create();
Four.prototype = {
    initialize : function(){

    },
    one:   new One(),
    two:   new Two(),
    three: new Three(),
    firstMethod: function(){
        var one = this.one;    //Initializing
        var two = this.two;
        var three = this.three;
        //do operations using the above class variables
    },
    secondMethod : function(){
        var one = this.one;    //again Initializing
        var two = this.two;
        //do operations using the above class variables
    }
}
```

**three.js**

```
var Three = Class.create();
Four.prototype = {
    initialize : function(){

    },
    one:   new One(),
    two:   new Two(),
    four: new Four(),
    firstMethod: function(){
        var one = this.one;    //Initializing
        var two = this.two;
        var four = this.four;
        //do operations using the above class variables
    },
    secondMethod : function(){
        var one = this.one;    //again Initializing
        var two = this.two;
        //do operations using the above class variables
    }
}
```

As you can see in the above code example, I am Initializing the class `One` two times in different methods of the class `Four`. This seems really worst because for every method I am initializing the same class which was already initialised.

**EDIT**: And also I am initializing `One` and `Two` classes more than once in js files `three.js` and `four.js`. The above explanation is just for example. Actually, in my project, there are js files more than 20.

In my project, I am following the same structure in all js files.

How should I make this structure efficient?

PS: A solution with less changes would be really helpful because this is a huge and running project and I don't want to take risks at this time.

Comment: Why are you making aliases for all the variables in each method? For example, your line `var one = this.one;    //Initializing`. That isn't *doing* anything, except letting you write `one` instead of `this.one` in the rest of the function.

Comment: @meagar if I use `this.one` everywhere then it will initialize for every called method which is more times than it is happening now.

Comment: That doesn't seem true? You're initializing it once, on the line `one:   new One(),`.

Comment: @meagar if I call it again then wouldn't that initialize again? I am thinking it will..

Comment: No. Try it, put a `console.log` in your `One` initialize method. Invoking `this.one` doesn't *initialize* anything. It just accesses the already initialized variable.

Comment: @Mr_Green what have you tried?

Comment: @meagar sorry, the actual problem is that I am loading some js files. In each file, I am initializing the other classes..

Comment: @vol7ron the structure which I explain is what I have tried. I don't want to share the code because it is not a bug finding issue.

Comment: I'm sorry, but you're not. Your just typing a bunch of lines that don't do anything. Get rid of all your `var one = this.one; var two = this.two` lines, and just use `this.one` and `this.two` in your methods.

Comment: @meagar okay I will do it. Sorry, but still I haven't understood why to do so? Is aliasing a problem here?

Comment: No, but it seems that you think it's required to avoid some repeated initialization, and it isn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you need separate versions in each method:

```
var Four = Class.create();

Four.prototype = {
  initialize : function(One, Two){
    // store for later use
    this.One = One;
    this.Two = Two;
  },
  firstMethod: function(){
      var one = new this.One(); // Initializing
      var two = new this.Two();
      //do operations using the above class variables
  },
  secondMethod : function(){
      var one = new this.One(); // again Initializing
      var two = new this.Two();
      //do operations using the above class variables
  }
};

// 'inject' needed class constructor functions
var four = new Four(One, Two);
```

In case you need single version for whole Four object:

```
var Four = Class.create();

Four.prototype = {
  initialize : function(One, Two){
    // initialize and use later this.Xxx
    this.One = new One();
    this.Two = new Two();
  },
  firstMethod: function(){
      //do operations using the above class variables
  },
  secondMethod : function(){
      //do operations using the above class variables
  }
};

// 'inject' needed class constructor functions
var four = new Four(One, Two);
```

**edit:**

```
var Four = Class.create();

Four.prototype = {
  initialize : function(one, two){
    // initialize and use later this.xxx
    this.one = one;
    this.two = two;
  },
  firstMethod: function(){
      //do operations using the above class variables
  },
  secondMethod : function(){
      //do operations using the above class variables
  }
};

// 'inject' needed objects
var four = new Four(new One(), new Two());
```

Comment: You simply cannot use code which doesn't exist. If you want to use it, you must load it.

Comment: Can I do like this? `var four = new Four(new One(), new Two());`.. any issues if I do like this?

Comment: Thanks, I got idea after seeing your answer. I will initialize all these classes in a new js file which runs when the dom is ready. :)

Comment: In this case, I think it may be better to pass arguments as an object: `var two = new Two(); var four = Four.initialize({two: Two});`  inside `initialize: function(params){ this.one = params.one || new One(); this.two = params.two || new Two(); }`